# Escaping form Values

Tags: asp.net

I have a ASP.NET login form from which the values are passed on to a third party tool to login to their portal. There is an issue which causes the login to fail if the value, for example the username is like so Kukkamäki
which has a non-english char in it.
The third party portal says that the form values shoule be escaped before sending it to them. I tried that using this \" but that does not work.

Any ideas on how to escape the form values?

Comment: How are you calling this third party? Could you show your current code?

Comment: Third party is a Webservice. It accepts username and password which are assigned the usual way. Then the authenticate method of ws is called passing in the username and password.

Answer (score 0):

before you send it to server you should use  :

`encodeURIComponent` function to encode the chars to a `utf8` .

then you should use this value as posted...

Also , ensure that your column DB type for this column is : `nvarchar` ( if you useing mssql)

Comment: Hi Royi, the third party is a webservice to which the username and password are assigned like so ws.username = txtUserName.text and ws.password = txtPassword.text. How do I use the encodeURIComponent function? Here is the form code <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnLogin" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/CSS/Images/SignIn.gif" onclick="imgbtnLogin_Click" />

Answer (score 0):

Two options, depending on what you need:

- use `escape()` function  ([link](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_escape.asp)) if you call their webservice from client side javascript
- use `HttpUtility.UrlEncode()` method ([link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/4fkewx0t%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)) if you call their webservice from server side code